# I get "Release of profile requested but WebEnginePage still not deleted. Expect troubles !" when PyQt5 application exits

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

When my Python 3.x apps exists, I get a message on the console

```
Release of profile requested but WebEnginePage still not deleted. Expect troubles !
```

and then python crashes

Windows 10 64 bit
Python 3.72 (32 bits)
PyQt5 4.19.18

Googled around an seen people reporting the problem (sometimes in C++), but not clear indication of what to do.

pretty simple case:

```py
class PmApplication(QMainWindow):
(...) 
     summary=QWebEngineView(self)
(...)
     tabWidget.addTab(summary,"Summary")
```

and at some point, I generate an HTML document with mako in another class that manages notifications (so, self.web points to summary)

```py
    data.trip = con.execute(sql).fetchall()
    html = self.template.render(d=data)
    self.web.setHtml(html)
    self.web.show()
```

This works fine until I close the application

I use PyDev, and while ran inside eclipse, I just see alert dialog from Python telling it crashed.

From the command line, I get

```
Release of profile requested but WebEnginePage still not deleted. Expect troubles !
```

and then the same dialog from Python

any pointer ? (also, new to python and PyQt5)

thanks

As suggested (and as I should have done), here's a minimal snippet that reproduces the problem

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import QtWebEngine
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings
from PyQt5.Qt import QHBoxLayout
import sys

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    pm = QMainWindow()
    centralWidget = QWidget(pm)  
    summary=QWebEngineView(pm)
    box = QHBoxLayout()
    box.addWidget(summary)
    centralWidget.setLayout(box)
    html = "<html><head><title>Here goes</title></head><body> Does this work ?</body></html>"
    summary.setHtml(html)
    pm.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Could you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Sorry, added to original post.

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce the problem as originally posed using PySide2 5.15.2, but I'm having it in my own code. Jocularity, jocularity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is caused by creating and executing the `QApplication` object from within a function. One way to fix the problem is to do something like.

```
def main(app):
    pm = QMainWindow()
    centralWidget = QWidget(pm)
    summary=QWebEngineView(pm)
    box = QHBoxLayout()
    box.addWidget(summary)
    centralWidget.setLayout(box)
    pm.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
    html = "<html><head><title>Here goes</title></head><body> Does this work ?</body></html>"
    summary.setHtml(html)
    pm.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main(app)
```

Alternatively you could move the code in `main()` directly into the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Comment: This fixes the issue.. thanks